# Clickable toggle to hover and stay and improve code

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm very new to jQuery and I'm building a page with multiple toggle divs.

In the example of what I have so far I have 3 clickable divs (`.info1`, `.info2`, `.info3`) which individually toggle other corresponding divs (`.infobox1`, `.infobox2`, `.infobox3`).

They are currently clickable because in the infobox I want links to click and I can't figure out how to make the infobox stay visible for maybe a second or two so you have time to hover off the info div over the infobox div without it disappear.

So I have two questions:

1. how can I make my code so I don't have to keep adding lines to toggle each time, `$('.infobox1').toggle();$('.infobox2').toggle(); $('.infobox3').toggle();` etc would become one and allow any number after info & infobox?
2. how can I make it so when I hover over info rather than click the infobox, so it stays up long enough for someone to move there mouse over it?

```js
$('.info1').click(function(){
    $('.infobox1').toggle();
});
$('.info2').click(function(){
    $('.infobox2').toggle();
});
$('.info3').click(function(){
    $('.infobox3').toggle();
});
```

```html
<div class="lb-info info1" style="margin-top: -52%; margin-left: 24%;"></div>
<a href="">
    <div class="lb-infobox infobox1" style="left: 26%; top: 22%;">
        Info1 <br />
        <span class="product-info">Info2</span> <br />
        Info3
    </div>
</a>

<div class="lb-info info2" style="margin-top: -25%; margin-left: 26%;"></div>
<a href="">
    <div class="lb-infobox infobox2" style="left: 6.5%; top: 58%;">
        Info1 <br />
        <span class="product-info">Info2</span> <br />
        Info3
    </div>
</a>

<div class="lb-info  info3" style="margin-top: -15%; margin-left: 26%;"></div>
<a href="">
    <div class="lb-infobox infobox3" style="left: 28%; top: 72%;">
        Info1 <br />
        <span class="product-info">Info2</span> <br />
        Info3
    </div>
</a>
```

Much appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a common class on the trigger div elements, and then traverse the DOM to find the element to toggle, something like this:

```
$('.lb-info').click(function(){
    $(this).next('a').find('.lb-infobox').toggle();
});
```

Comment: Thanks that seems to simplify the code to allow multiple instances, do you have any idea about the hovering over a lb-info instead of clicking and allowing lb-infobox to stay visible for a second or two to allow a user to move the mouse from one to the other without disappearing on mouse off.

Comment: So I have this:

    <script>
    $('.lb-info').hover(function(){
        $(this).next('a').find('.lb-infobox').toggle( 300 );
    
    });
    </script>

But I just can't get the lb-infobox to stay as soon as you mouse off the lb-info